# How to split large json array into pages in Android

Tags: android, json, rest, api

I'm fetching json data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos, and want to split this data into pages so that I can implement the Android Paging Library in my app. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Page 1 (returns photos for id 1 to 10):
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=0&_limit=10

Page 2 (returns photos for id 11 to 20)
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=10&_limit=10

Comment: Thanks. Must I manually set these values in the URL each time?

Answer (score 0):

> For paginatio you will use android jetpack
>   https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

1. Another method
2. get specific number of data from api and add into recyleview after that do something like below after loading your specific data again you will call further remaining specific data make a counter for counting loaded data.
3. getalltemlist() is a method from where u get ur json.
4. Reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-vZ1g_G1Zo

   ```
        boolean isScrolling=false;

      rView.setAdapter(adapter);
      rView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
          @Override
          public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int 
         newState) {
              super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
              if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL)
              {
                  isScrolling=true;
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
              super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
              currentitems=layoutManager.getChildCount();
              totaliitems=layoutManager.getItemCount();
              scrolloutitems=layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
              if(isScrolling && (currentitems + scrolloutitems == totaliitems))
              {
                  isScrolling=false;
                  getAllItemList();
              }
          }
      });
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   getAllItemList();
   ```